# Does the Raspberry Pi 4 support HDCP?

Tags: hdmi, video, streaming-video

I could not find a definitive answer anywhere in the specs or on the web.

I am looking for a device that will allow me to play Amazon Movies (and those of other platforms) in 4K.

Thank you!

Comment: The chip supports HDCP and is used on other platforms where the content provider insists, and the content is DRM protected.
The Raspberry Pi has no such deals in place, and so HDCP is disabled.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*@MichaelHarvey* wrote in a comment:

> The chip supports HDCP and is used on other platforms where the content provider insists, and the content is DRM protected. The Raspberry Pi has no such deals in place, and so HDCP is disabled.